# python object composition and multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, object-composition

If I implement object composition with **getattr** and pass the object into a new process, I get an RecursionError from **getattr**. Here is an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return getattr(self._bar, attr)
        except RecursionError:
            print('RecursionError while trying to access {}'.format(attr))
            raise AttributeError

def f(foo):
    print(foo.bar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(Bar('baz'))
    f(foo)
    p = Pool(1)
    p.map(f, [foo])
```

The output is this:

```
baz
RecursionError while trying to access _bar
baz
```

Why doesn't Foo find the _bar attribute and has to resort to **getattr**?

Comment: What is this: `foo = Foo(Bar('baz'))`? What does it do in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Python needs to serialize the `foo` object and resurrect it in the new process. `__init__` isn't called during resurrection, so your `foo` object won't have a `._bar` attribute early enough.

The solution is to let the serialize/resurrect methods through specially, ie. change your `__getattr__` to:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr in {'__getstate__', '__setstate__'}:
        return object.__getattr__(self, attr)
    return getattr(self._bar, attr)
```

and it should work.